# firebase database display user info error

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display my user's data based on who is logged in. Right now my function isn't reading anything from my database. This is the current error that i'm getting:
firebase-database.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'studioName'). I checked to make sure that the id was correct and in my databse as well. Also, one last thing, how can I make sure that the user is still logged in when I navigate to other pages? I have provided my code below. Thank you!

Firebase Database:

[image: firebase database screenshot]

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <!---Required meta tags--->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/studiodash.css">
  
    <!---Required meta tags--->

    <!---Like Button JavaScript--->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f6dcf461c1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!---Bootstrap CSS--->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>StudioPick</title>
    <script>
      

      // SignOut
      function signOut() {
          auth.signOut();
          alert("SignOut Successfully from System");

          window.location.href ="login.html?error";
          alert("No active user please sign or sign up.");
      }
  

    </script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <!---Navbar--->
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-curresnt="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item2">
                  <div class="action">
                    <div class="profile" onclick="menuToggle();">
                      <img src="./assets/avatar.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu">
                      <h3 id="profile-name"><strong>User Name</strong></h3>
                      <p class="text-muted" id="userType" style="position: relative; top: -50px; right: -51px; font-size: 10px !important">profile type</p>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <img src="./assets/icons/user.png" /><a href="studiodash.html">Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <img src="./assets/icons/edit.png" /><a href="editprofile.html">Edit profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <img src="./assets/icons/envelope.png" /><a href="#">Inbox</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <img src="./assets/icons/settings.png" /><a href="#">Setting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="./assets/icons/question.png" /><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                        <li>
                          <img src="./assets/icons/log-out.png" /><a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!---Navbar--->

    
    <!---Dashboard Body--->
    <div class="container" id="dashboard">
      <h1 class="page-title"><strong>Studio Dashboard</strong></h1>
      <!---Booking Calendar--->
      <div class="notifications">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Schedule</strong></h5>
        </div>




        <button class="calendar-view">View Full Calendar</button>
      </div>
      <!---Booking Calendar--->
      <!---Edit Profile--->
      <div class="edit-profile" id="edit-profile">
        <div class="card-body">
          <form id="studioForm">
            <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Edit Profile</strong></h5>
            <p class="profile-title" id="studioName"><b>Enter Studio Name</b></p>
            <p class="profile-location" id="profile-location">Bethesda, MD</p>
            <img class="star" src="Images/Star.png">
            <p class="profile-rating" id="profile-rating">4.25</p>
            <p class="profile-reviews" id="profile-reviews">8 reviews</p>
            
            <img class="card-img-bottom" id="profile-image" src="Images/placeholder.png">

            <button type="button" id="editprofilebutton" onclick="window.location.href='editprofile.html'">Edit Profile</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---Edit Profile--->
      <!---Current Session--->
      <div class="session-info">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Current Session</strong></h5>
          <div class="current-client">
            
            
          </div>
          <p class="current-date text-muted">Date:</p>
            <p class="todays-date">08/30/2022</p>
          <p class="current-service text-muted">Service:</p>
            <p class="todays-service">W Engineer</p>
          <p class="current-room text-muted">Room:</p>
          <p class="todays-room">A</p>
          <p class="current-duration text-muted">Duration:</p>
            <p class="todays-duration">3 hours</p>
          <p class="current-start-time text-muted">Start Time:</p>
          <p class="todays-start-time">4:00 pm</p>
          <p class="current-end-time text-muted">End Time:</p>
            <p class="todays-end-time">7:00 pm</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---Current Session--->
      <!---Payment History--->
      <div class="payment-history">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Payment History</strong></h5>
          <div class="transaction">
            <p class="customer">- Highway</p>
            <p class="payment">+ $1,000</p>
          </div>
          <div class="transaction-two">
            <p class="customer2">- TyFontaine</p>
            <p class="payment2">+ $1,000</p>
          </div>
          <button class="history-view">View Payment History</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---Payment History--->
      <!---Upcoming Sessions--->
      <div class="sessions">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Upcoming Sessions</strong></h5>
          <div class="new-session">
            <p class="session-price">$100</p>
            <p class="customer-name">Grmln!</p>
            <p class="session-room text-muted">Room A: </p>
            <p class="session-type text-muted">No Engineer</p>
            <p class="session-length text-muted">2:00 pm - 4:00 pm</p>
            <p class="session-date text-muted">08/27/2022</p>
          </div>
          <div class="new-session2">
            <p class="session-price2">$100</p>
            <p class="customer-name2">Grmln!</p>
            <p class="session-room2 text-muted">Room A: </p>
            <p class="session-type2 text-muted">No Engineer</p>
            <p class="session-length2 text-muted">2:00 pm - 4:00 pm</p>
            <p class="session-date2 text-muted">08/27/2022</p>
          </div>
          <div class="new-session3">
            <p class="session-price3">$100</p>
            <p class="customer-name3">Grmln!</p>
            <p class="session-room3 text-muted">Room A: </p>
            <p class="session-type3 text-muted">No Engineer</p>
            <p class="session-length3 text-muted">2:00 pm - 4:00 pm</p>
            <p class="session-date3 text-muted">08/27/2022</p>
          </div>
          <button class="upcoming-view">View Upcoming Sessions</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!---Upcoming Sessions--->
    <!---Session Status--->
    <div class="session-status">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Session Status</strong></h5>
        <div class="session-option">
          <button class="accept-button">Accept</button>
          <button class="reject-button">Reject</button>
          <button class="change-button">Change Time/Date</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!---Session Status--->
    <!---Pending Sessions--->
    <div class="pending-sessions">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Pending Sessions</strong></h5>
        <div class="pending">
            <p class="pending-session-price">$100</p>
            <p class="pending-customer-name">Joony</p>
            <p class="pending-session-room text-muted">Room A: </p>
            <p class="pending-session-type text-muted">No Engineer</p>
            <p class="pending-session-length text-muted">2:00 pm - 4:00 pm</p>
            <p class="pending-session-date text-muted">08/27/2022</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pending2">
            <p class="pending-session-price2">$100</p>
            <p class="pending-customer-name2">Tae Dawg</p>
            <p class="pending-session-room2 text-muted">Room D: </p>
            <p class="pending-session-type2 text-muted">With Engineer</p>
            <p class="pending-session-length2 text-muted">2:00 pm - 4:00 pm</p>
            <p class="pending-session-date2 text-muted">09/27/2022</p>
        </div>
        <button class="pending-view">View Pending Sessions</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!---Pending Sessions--->
    <!---Edit Prices--->
    <div class="edit-prices">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Edit Prices</strong></h5>
        <div class="roomA">
          <p class="description-one">Room A:</p>
          <p class="type text-muted">With Engineer</p>
          <p class="dollarsign-one">$</p>
          <p class="price-one">45</p>
          <p class="time-type">/Hr</p>
        </div>
        <div class="roomB">
          <p class="description-two">Room B:</p>
          <p class="type2 text-muted">With Engineer</p>
          <p class="dollarsign-two">$</p>
          <p class="price-two">50</p>
          <p class="time-type2">/Hr</p>
        </div>
        <button class="editPrice-button">Edit Prices</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!---Edit Prices--->
    <!---Messages--->
    <div class="messages">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Messages</strong></h5>
        <div class="notification-one">
          <p class="person-one">Chris Brown</p>
          <p class="text-one text-muted">I'm omw. 20 mins out. I ran into some traffic bc of this real bad accident. If I don't get there in time, I'll pay extra. </p>
          <p class="time-occurred-one text-muted">3 min ago</p>
        </div>
        <div class="notification-two">
          <p class="person-two">Kanye West</p>
          <p class="text-two text-muted">I'm omw. 45 mins out. I ran into some traffic bc of this real bad accident. If I don't get there in time, I'll pay extra. </p>
          <p class="time-occurred-two text-muted">12 min ago</p>
        </div>
        <button class="view-messages">View Messages</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!---Messages--->
    <!---Footer--->
    <footer class="my-5 pt-5 text-muted text-center text-small">
      <p class="mb-1">© 2022 StudioPick.</p>
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      </ul>
    </footer>
    <!---Footer--->
    <!---Dashboard Body--->

    <script>
      function menuToggle() {
        const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".menu");
        toggleMenu.classList.toggle("active");
      }
    </script>

    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <!---Javascript--->
    <script src="Javascript/studiodash.js"></script>
    <!---Javascript--->
    
    <!----More Bootstrap--->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!----More Bootstrap--->
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize variables
const auth = firebase.auth();
const database = firebase.database();

//Check if user is signed in and display info
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    database.ref('/studiopick/studio/users/'+ user.uid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
      document.getElementById("studioName").innerText = snapshot.val().studioName;
    })
  } else {
    window.location.href ="login.html?error";
    alert("No active user please sign or sign up.");
  }
});
```

Comment: Any specific security rules that would prevent the user reading the DB node?

Comment: Do you see an error if you do `database.ref('/studiopick/studio/users/'+user.uid).get().then(snapshot =>{document.getElementById("studioName").innerText = snapshot.val().studioName;}).catch(e => {console.log(e)})`. In addition note that you should update to V8.10.1, or better, to V9.

Comment: yes. this is the error: Error: Error: Client is offline.
    at Repo.ts:482:29

Comment: and how can I update my firebase?

Comment: Just change all the lines `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/...` to `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/...`. Then retry.

Comment: Got a new error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'studioName')
    at studiodash.js:23:143

Comment: Can you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot))` in the `then` block?

Comment: subscribe.ts:239 ReferenceError: snapshot is not defined
    at Object.next (studiodash.js:23:94)
    at subscribe.ts:104:16
    at subscribe.ts:233:11

Comment: Repo.ts:482 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: Client is offline.
    at Repo.ts:482:29